# swift 2.0 convert UIFontDescriptorSymbolicTraits to CTFontSymbolicTraits

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, uifont, uifontdescriptor

How I can convert a `UIFontDescriptorSymbolicTraits` to `CTFontSymbolicTraits` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at how they are defined. Here is CTFontSymbolicTraits:

```
enum {
kCTFontItalicTrait = (1 << 0),
kCTFontBoldTrait = (1 << 1),
kCTFontExpandedTrait = (1 << 5),
kCTFontCondensedTrait = (1 << 6),
// ...
};
typedef uint32_t CTFontSymbolicTraits;
```

Here is UIFontDescriptorSymbolicTraits:

```
typedef enum : uint32_t {
   UIFontDescriptorTraitItalic = 1u << 0,
   UIFontDescriptorTraitBold = 1u << 1,
   UIFontDescriptorTraitExpanded = 1u << 5,
   UIFontDescriptorTraitCondensed = 1u << 6,
   // ...
} UIFontDescriptorSymbolicTraits;
```

Notice anything? As far as the traits that matter to you are concerned, they are in fact identical. There is nothing to convert.

Comment: then how I'd handle that with the compiler? The method *`CTFontCreateCopyWithSymbolicTraits(font: CTFont, _ size: CGFloat, _ matrix: UnsafePointer<CGAffineTransform>, _ symTraitValue: CTFontSymbolicTraits, _ symTraitMask: CTFontSymbolicTraits) -> CTFont?`* wants *`CTFontSymbolicTraits`* type

Comment: the only this is that I have a *`UIFontDescriptor`* that gives me the description of the selected text in the *`UITextView`* . I need to support Bold and Italic (and those ones can be combined).